# Batch file, query the registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello People of StackoverFlow,

I am trying to query the follow registry location(every folder in here)
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

In there are random numbers like so:

```
{071c9b48-7c32-4621-a0ac-3f809523288f}
```

In each of these random numbers, I need to check if the key 'DisplayName' that is in each of these locations contains a certain text, lets say 'OverFlow'.

I've done some querys but not like this, if anyone can help that would be great!

EDIT: I've made some progress but am encountering a problem( I have done alot of research...)

Below is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

setlocal


:RemoveCVCP
set PythonReg=
for /f "tokens=1"  %%A in ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /v "DisplayName" ^| find "Python"') do set "PythonReg=%%A"
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
GOTO RemovePyCP)
echo %PythonReg%

endlocal

pause
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through 'KLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', and look at the 'DisplayName' key, if the data contains 'Python' then delete it. and keep going till there are no longer any more.

Right Now I am testing this with an echo, but it will evetually delete it.

(I'm just using python as an example, I have already removed everything else that is related to the software I'm trying to remove, this is the last location.)

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Are you sure you only want to search in entries like you described? (btw, those are [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)s). There are other entries too, some applications are listed there by name.

Comment: Wait..  What about this?  http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/07/view-installed-programs-one-powershell-command/ This should show the detail you are seeking.

Comment: I need to do this in batch, as my whole script 700+ lines is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, list all values that contain `python`, two lines will be printed for each entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E43BBAEB-4914-44C6-88C0-E7A1DBD20A91}
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Some application title with python in its name
```

then delete those keys where the printed value name is `DisplayName`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('^
    reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /d /f "python"^
') do (
    if "%%A"=="DisplayName" (
        echo Deleting %%C
        reg delete !key! /f
    ) else (
        set str=%%A
        if "!str:~0,4!"=="HKEY" set key=%%A
    )
)
pause
```

This code assumes there are no spaces in the key name.

Comment: Amazing, I've been trying all day. Thank you for the response, Can I ask that you break down that code, what does it do inparticular. Alot of it I haven't used yet..

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward, what exactly you want explained?

Comment: You use ^ in the beginning of the reg query and at the end, why? Also %%C is not defined anwhere, I'm assuming its set by the token '1,2'?

And this :  reg delete !key! /f
    ) else (
        set str=%%A
        if "!str:~0,4!"=="HKEY" set key=%%A

Excuse the questions, I am really trying to get into scripting :)

Comment: `^` makes it possible to write the command on several lines for readability.  `%%A` is a first word (token), `%%B` 2nd, `%%C` receives all space-delimited words after the first two tokens ([more info](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)). These are very basic things. If you're really interested in using batch files find some tutorial